# Distributing NUnit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I am trying to distribute some c# code made in visual studio 2010 that has some NUnit tests included.  Is there a way to distribute it so that others don't have to install NUnit, but can still run the tests in some form?  The one thought that came to mind was putting the dll's in the project directory and referencing -those- in the Visual Studio project, and then zipping up the entire directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit tests require NUnit. The only assembly needed to be referenced/provided run standard unit tests is nunit.framework.dll. As long as you include that assembly the solution would build.

A simple reference in your doco/page that unit tests are NUnit are enough for developers to know and they can either download NUnit to run them or something like TDD.Net which executes NUnit tests.

For plug & play you'd otherwise be stuck with MSTest tests.